# Iterating Through Links With Selenium WebDriver w/ C#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code

I have a project to click through specific links on a web page using Selenium WebDriver with C# and I'm struggling to find a clean way to iterate through them with an array that accounts for specific cases.

I understand how to do basic driver.FindElement(By.XPath(" "));

But I'm not sure how I could create a WebElement Array to feed a foreach statement that would search By.TagName("a") in specific div classes without pulling every link on the page.

Example of what the header of the website looks like:

```html
<header>
    <div id="ContainerTopStrip">
        <div class="ContainerWidth">
            <div class="headerMenu">
                <a href="Account/IntakeLogin" title="Report">Report</a>
                <a href="/rfs" title="Request">Request</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openFullWindow();" title="Lookup">Lookup</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Basic example of what I have just using findelement:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\"))
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("xxx");
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[text()=\"xxx\"]")).Click();
            // TODO: Figure out how to assert route change occurred

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[text()=\"xxx\"]")).Click();
            driver.Navigate().Back();

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[text()=\"xxx/I\")]")).Click();
            driver.Navigate().Back();

            Console.WriteLine("This is what happens when you don't know how to make an array.");
            driver.Quit();
        }    
    }
}
```

So to summarize:

Need help finding a way to create an array that could find specific links to be clicked in a loop because that seemed like the neatest solution after searching for awhile now. If there is a better suggestion available, I'm open to it. Just completely new to C#/Selenium in general.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the links by determining the xpath of links

```
var links = myWebDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/header/div[1]/div/div/a"));

//loop through all header links
for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
{
    //reassignment because of reloading the page after each navigation
    links = myWebDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/header/div[1]/div/div/a"));
    myWebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(links[i].GetAttribute("href"));
    //or you can click
    //links[i].Click();
    myWebDriver.Navigate().Back();
}
```

and for the next links is shown in the picture :

```
var links2 = myWebDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/header/div[2]/div/ul/li/a"));
for (int i = 0; i < links2.Count; i++)
{
    links2 = myWebDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/header/div[2]/div/ul/li/a"));
    myWebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(links2[i].GetAttribute("href"));
    //or you can click        
    //links2[i].Click();
    myWebDriver.Navigate().Back();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FindElements` method provided by selenium to get all elements inside a list. Then you can use the `GetAttribute()` method to get `href` and navigate to each of them.

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elementList = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//div[@class='headerMenu']"));
foreach (IWebElement item in t){
Driver.Navigate.GoToUrl(item.GetAttribute("href"));
Driver.Navigate().Back();
}
```